# remove deleted files from git: Argument list too long

Tags: macos, git, bash

I try to remove deleted files from git:

```
git rm `git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $3}'`
```

But got error in **mac bash**:

```
-bash: /usr/local/git/bin/git: Argument list too long
```

If I run ...

```
git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $3}'
```

... I successfully got list of files to be deleted. But how to delete them from git?

Comment: Are you looking for git add -A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs` will limit the command length to something the shell won't choke on and invoke the command passed as many times as required.

```
git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $3}' | xargs git rm
```

Comment: Be careful with this. I'd prefer to grep on "deleted:". Also, if a file name contains "deleted:", it will be removed from git source control.

Comment: Grep for "^\s*deleted:" instead if you don't want to delete filenames containing the text "deleted:".

Comment: How can I combine this with rm -r --cached?  Simply adding the -r --cached to the command doesn't work.  I get the usage hint.

Comment: In case anyone else comes here and copies this examples and gets confused like I did: I had to change $3 to $2 in the awk command.